# how to analyze calls made from an iphone app

Tags: iphone, networking, tampering

Is it possible to monitor the network calls (http and https) made from an iPhone application? Is it possible to install a proxy server and log all the network calls made in the network?

Comment: when you say "calls" do you mean network connections?

Comment: Yes i meant the network calls made from the apps to the server. I have edited the question. thank you

Answer (score 2):

There is an awesome tool called [Charles](http://www.charlesproxy.com).

I use it all the time to check network calls and stuff. There are instructions on the site of how to set up your computer as a proxy for your iPhone.

Once this is done you can then filter out the results that are collected by URL etc... so you can just see your app's calls.

Answer (score 1):

Can you explain exactly why you want to do this. For debugging purpose, here is what I suggest:

- option 1: use the simulator, and a tools on your mac to track all the network calls (you can use [wireshark](https://www.wireshark.org/) for instance)
- option 2: connect the device to a computer in Wifi, and then track all the network calls on this computer

Comment: I have an old enterprise app for which I don't have the code. I tried resigning the app (to do a method swizzle and implement custom nsurlprotocol) but resigning doesn't work and the app crashes. The backend team contact person is on vacation so I thought I could try something on my own. For option two do I need to install any tools on the mac? can you explain a little more..

Comment: Yes, you need tools on the mac, for instance, follow this tutorial: http://www.charlesproxy.com/documentation/faqs/using-charles-from-an-iphone/